# Why does a 'javascript:..' snippet not work in Firefox' address bar?

Tags: javascript

The following works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (27) when entered (not pasted) into the URL bar:

```
javascript:alert('hi')
```

Why?

Comment: It works in Firefox 35.0.1

Comment: In what version of FF?

Comment: 27 is in his post, yet still this should work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 36.0 Nothing happens at all.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Try actually typing everything instead of copy/pasting, it'll work

Comment: @blex ah, indeed. Interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript URIs, entered directly into the address bar, are banned in a number of browsers as a defence against social engineering based bookmarklet pasting attacks.

An example of such an attack would be "Go to Facebook and paste this into your address bar in order to see who has viewed your page" where the code would actually grant full access to your profile to the attacker.

Some browsers may distinguish between pasted and typed scripts (on the basis that a typed one is unlikely to be an attack).

- [Bug 527530 - Social Engineering Issue with "javascript:" URLs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527530)

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about typing, not pasting.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Javascript. It is simply a matter of how a browser interprets a piece of text when entered in the navigation (url) bar. For instance in Opera if you type `hello world` it will go to your default search engine and search for `hello world`, while `g hello world` will force it to go to Google to search.

Likewise with Javascript, if the browser wants to execute it, it will. But if not, it is simply not going to happen.

Comment: It feels like JavaScript URIs would be standardised in some way though.